# CorePlot: How to add a plotting point to CurvedScatterPlot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am using CorePlot for the first time now for graphs. My graph is showing ok. Everything is drawn ok. I was searching but I could not find answer to this question: how to mark maximum and minimum point on my graph with a plotting point and how to show that value above or below that point? I do not want to show value of every point. I've seen some comments to use this:

`-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index`

but how to use that thing?

**EDIT:**  I've added plotting points using `CPTPlotSymbol`. The problem is, I want to add `CPTPlotSymbol` only for two values. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot different plot symbols at each point on a scatter plot. Implement the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method and return the appropriate symbol for each data index. Return `[NSNull null]` if you don't want a symbol at that index. Return `nil` to use the plot's `plotSymbol` at that index.

Answer (score 2):

In preparing your plot, find and store indices of min/max points:

```
NSUInteger indexOfMin = ...
NSUInteger indexOfMax = ...
```

Then in `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` :

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (plot.identifier == yourPlotID) // optional if you only have one plot
    {
        if (index == indexOfMin)
        {
            return [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"Your Min Label"];
        }
        else if (index == indexOfMax)
        {
            return [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"Your Max Label"];
        }
    }
    return  nil;
}
```